# Splitting a single word into an array of the consituent letters

Tags: asp-classic

I'm familiar with using the Split function in a classic ASP page to split e.g. a string at each comma,

e.g.

```
<%
my_string ="jon@doe.com, bob@bob.com, me@you.com"

MyArray = Split(my_string,",")

For i=0 to UBound(MyArray)
    loop_email = trim(myArray(i))
    response.write "Email: " & loop_email & "<br />"
Next
%>
```

Output:

```
Email: jon@doe.com
Email: bob@bob.com
Email: me@you.com
```

I'd like to take a string which is just a single word, e.g. "cat", and split that into separate letters,

So that instead of the example above, the output would be:

```
Letter: c
Letter: a
Letter: t
```

I'm stuck trying to figure that out though as there is no obvious delimiter, as in the comma example.

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just loop through the length of the string getting the individual letters. If you only need them in an array in order to loop through them, then this should suit just fine. If you need an array, I think you'd need to loop through them and build the array yourself.

```
Dim str, i
str = "cat"
For i = 1 To Len(str)
    Response.Write "<p>" & Mid(str, i, 1) & "</p>"
Next
```